# remove empty xmlns="" attribute using php

Tags: php, xml

I have tried all the possible ways to remove the empty xmlns from tags, Please help to solve this issue.

```
$XMLDoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$XMLDoc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$XMLDoc->formatOutput = true;
$soap = $XMLDoc->createElementNS('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/', 'soap:Envelope');
$XMLDoc->appendChild($soap);
$soap->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
$soap->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,'xmlns:xsd', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
$soap->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,'xmlns:soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
$body = $XMLDoc->createElementNS('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/', 'soap:Body');
$XMLDoc->appendChild($body);
include 'DBDetails.php';
$XMlQuery="SELECT `First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `Email`, `Pan_No`, `Res_address`, `Res_address2`, `Res_address3`, `Resi_type`, `Mobile`, `Res_City`, `Resi_City_other`, `Resi_City_other1`, `res_pin`, `Company_name`, `DateOfBirth`, `Designation`, `Emp_type`, `Monthly_income`, `card_held`, `Source_code`, `Promo_code`, `LEAD_DATE_TIME`, `PRODUCT_APPLIED_FOR`, `existingcust`, `LoanAmt`, `YrsinEmp`, `emi_paid`, `car_make`, `car_model`, `TypeOfLoan`, `IP_Address`, `Indigo_UniqueKey`, `Indigo_RequestFromYesNo` FROM `webservice` WHERE `Source_code` LIKE '$Sourcecode'";
$rowcount=-1;
if($result=mysqli_query($conn,$XMlQuery))  {
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
}
if($rowcount>0){
$StockCount=-1;
$rootElement  = $XMLDoc->createElement('AddDetails');
$rootNode=$body->appendChild($rootElement);
while($result_array =  $result->fetch_assoc())  {
$StockCount++;
foreach($result_array as $key => $value)  {
 $value=trim($value);
if($value=="NULL" || $value=="" ||$value==-1){
$value="";
}
$rootNode->appendChild($XMLDoc->createElement($key,$value));
}
}
mysqli_close($conn);
}
$XSLDoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xslstr = '<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
        <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />                  
          <xsl:template match="/">    
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />    
          </xsl:template>                
          <xsl:template match="AddDetails">
            <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                           xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
              <soap:Body>
                <AddDetails xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> 
                  <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
                </AddDetails>
              </soap:Body>
            </soap:Envelope>
          </xsl:template>                   
        </xsl:transform>';
$XSLDoc->loadXML($xslstr);
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($XSLDoc);
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($XMLDoc);
echo $newXML;
```

It's resulting out as

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<AddDetails xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<First_Name xmlns="">TestFName</First_Name>
<Last_Name xmlns="">TestLName</Last_Name>
<Email xmlns="">test@gfdg.co.in</Email>
</AddDetails>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I would like to generate the XML like this

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<AddDetails xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<First_Name>TestFName</First_Name>
<Last_Name>TestLName</Last_Name>
<Email>test@gfdg.co.in</Email>
</AddDetails>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Please help me. i want to generate the code without empty xmlns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Quick and dirty patch.*

Just before the last line:

```
echo $newXML;
```

Add this:

```
$newXML = str_replace('xmlns=""', '', $newXML);
```

Comment: This is not a solution, just a cleanup! You need to add the same xmlns statements to your XSLT string to avoid the blank default xmlns attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the missing namespace declarations in your XSLT string.

If the namespaces from your XML document are not added to your XSLT document, the processor adds the blank default xmlns attributes.

Try adding all namespaces from your XML file to your XSLT string, this should resolve the blank xmlns attributes issues..